# me dice error cuando me logeo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

que tal disculpen tengo una duda resultaque estoy haciendo un login de usuarios pero me aparece error cuando meto los usuarios ya que el registro de usuarios si me los toma sin problema pero no puedo logearme

Notice: Undefined variable: conexion in C:\xampp\htdocs\deportes\LoginPHP\verificar.php on line 5

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\deportes\LoginPHP\verificar.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\deportes\LoginPHP\verificar.php on line 5

```
<?php

include ("conexion.php");
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $query = $conexion->query(" SELECT idusuarios FROM usuarios WHERE password='$password' and usuario='$usuario'");

    while ($result = $query->fetch_object()) {
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $_SESSION['password'] = $row['usuario'];
            header('location:admin.php');
        } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Datos incorrectos!</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

este es el formulario

```
<form  method="POST" action="verificar.php" >
<fieldset>
<label class="block clearfix">
<span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
</span>
</label>
<div class="clearfix">
<button type="button" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-danger">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
<span class="bigger-110">Enviar</span>
</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mandar el codigo de conexion.php?, gracias!, no olvides quitar los datos privados!

Comment: <?php
   
    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        include ("configuracion.php");
        $conexion = new mysqli ($server,$user,$pass,$bd);
    
        if (!$conexion) {
           
            $msg="Conexión imposible. Revise las credenciales de conexión";

Comment: } else {
            
            $usuario=!empty($_POST['usuario']) ? $_POST['usuario'] : NULL;
            $password=!empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : NULL;
   $repassword=!empty($_POST['repassword']) ? $_POST['repassword'] : NULL;
   
          
            $nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
   $correo=!empty($_POST['correo']) ? $_POST['correo'] : NULL;

            if($usuario && $password && $repassword && $nombre) { 
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';

Comment: $rec = $conexion->query($sql); 
               
                $verificar_usuario = FALSE;
         
                 while($result = $rec->fetch_object()) { 
                    if($result->usuario == $usuario) { 
                        $verificar_usuario = TRUE; 
                       
                            break; 
                    }
                } 
          
if(!$verificar_usuario) {

Comment: if($password == $repassword) {

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,correo,usuario,password) VALUES
    ('$nombre','$correo','$usuario','$password')";
 
  if

Comment: ($conexion->query($sql) && $conexion->affected_rows > 0) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Usted se ha registrado correctamente.");
  window.location.href="index.php";
  </script>';
  
  
  
 } else {

Comment: $msg="Error en la inserción";
 }
} else { 
 $msg="Las claves no son iguales, intente nuevamente."; 
} 
} else {

$msg="Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente."; 
} 

} else {
$msg="Por favor llene todos los campos. Faltan datos en el POST";
}
}

} else {
$msg="";  
}

echo $msg;

Comment: lo conecte al localhost

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que $conexion no esta inicializado. En include ("conexion.php"); no esta funcionando correctamente.

Comment: y como puedo arrancarlo bien

Comment: Pasa el contenido del php